# MARP: How to embed an iframe in the presentation?

Tags: markdown, marp

I would like to embed an `.html` file in my [MARP](https://marp.app/) presentation, like an interactive chart for example.

Is there a way to do this?

I guess [this issue](https://github.com/yhatt/marp/issues/29) was relevant but in previous version of MARP.

Answer (score 1):

Noticed it works if `--html` is passed to the cli.

https://github.com/marp-team/marp-core/pull/9

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't working for me because of something weird going on with the closing tag. I fixed it by adding an explicit one:

```html
bad
<iframe src="https://example.com"/>

good
<iframe src="https://example.com"></iframe>
```